# Skiping relationship creation if already exist, not about MERGE

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am new to neo4j, my data is in csv files trying load them in db and create relationships.

departments.csv(9 rows)

```
dept_name
dept_no
```

dept_emp.csv(331603 rows)

```
dept_no
emp_no
from_date
to_date
```

I have create nodes with labels departments and dept_emp with all columns as properties. now trying to create relationship between them.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
load csv with headers from 'file:///dept_emp.csv' as row return row",
"match(de:dept_emp)
match(d:departments)
where de.dept_no=row.dept_no and d.dept_no= row.dept_no
merge (de)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(d)",{batchSize:10000, parallel:false})
```

I do have indexes on :dept_emp and :departments

When I try to run this it is taking ages to complete(many days). When I change the batch size to 10 it created 331603 relations, but it kept on running until it completes all the batches which is taking too long. When it encounters 9 different dept_no at initial rows in dept_emp.csv it is creating all the relations but it has to complete all the batches. In each batch it has to scan all the 331603 relations which were create in first two batches or so. Please help me with optimizing this.

Here I have used apoc.periodic.iterate to deal with the huge data in future, here how the data is related and how I am trying to establish the relation is making the problem . Each department will be having many dept_emp nodes connected.

Currently using Neo4j 4.2.1 version

Max heap size is 1G due to my laptop limitations.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create nodes in this fashion, i.e. set properties and then load the same csv again but match all nodes in the graph and do a cartesian join.

Instead:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///departments.csv' AS row
CREATE (d:Department) SET d.deptNo=row.dept_no, d.name=row.dept_name
```

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///dept_emp.csv' AS row
MATCH (d:Department {deptNo:row.`dept_no`})
WITH d
MERGE (e:Employee {empNo: row.`emp_no`})
MERGE (e)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(d)
```

Comment: I do agree, I don't need to create in that fashion.currently I am generating the cypher as well using metadata around data in python. Using py2neo to run them. i don't have that flexibility now, so looking for solution around that scenario. where in i have nodes already populated and trying to establish relationship among them. huge imbalance of data and checking all the relations for each row in dept_emp.csv. is the bottle neck here. I do agree its not the way to go. I tried with optional match combination with foreach. But every this comes to that bottle neck

Comment: I have tried your code, it taking more that 5 hours. one thing that need to edited is, you need to pass "row" as well in "with clause" otherwise it is not available in the second part of cypher.

Comment: considering the current scenario that best I got is loding departments.csv insted of dept_emp.csv. as it has only 9 rows and will cover all relations. it took me less than 30 secounds.

Comment: new version of new neo4j is not accepting "USING PERIODIC COMMIT" directly, have to add ":auto" in front of it. ":auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT".

Comment: match(de:dept_emp)
match(d:departments)
where de.dept_no= d.dept_no
merge (de)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(d)  this is taking me 16 seconds, but not feasible will have memory issues for huge data.

Comment: How much heap is assigned to Neo4j?

Comment: min is 512mb and max is 1G

Comment: That's probably too small, and so your overall process is going to take much longer to run. Maybe you can try the import tool https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin-import/#neo4j-admin-import